# AngularJS - how to disable OPTION request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, request, http-options-method

I noticed that my Angular is creating OPTIONS request also before each POST request.

I'm using custom API Service for HTTP request handling.

```
app.service('ApiService', function ($http) {

/**
 * Process remote POST request to give URL with given params
 * @param {String} url
 * @param {String} POST params
 * @return {JSON}  response from server
 */
this.doHttpRequest = function (type, url, params) {
    return $http({
        method: type,
        url: url,
        data: params,
        timeout: 5000,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    });
}

});
```

**Question is:**

How can i disable it (which config values put where)?

Is OPTIONS good for something? 
I think that is it something like "Handshake between 2 servers".

**Angular version: 1.2.15**

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That isn't Angular. It is XMLHttpRequest.

Complex cross-origin HTTP requests require [a pre-flight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) so the browser can find out if the other server will grant permission for the Ajax request.

Short of making sure the Ajax request you are making is [simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests), there is no way to prevent the OPTIONS request.

A simple request:

> - Only uses GET, HEAD or POST. If POST is used to send data to the server, the Content-Type of the data sent to the server with the HTTP POST request is one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.
> - Does not set custom headers with the HTTP Request (such as X-Modified, etc.)

Unless you wish to give up sending JSON, you can't use a simple request for this.

Answer (score 3):

I run into a close situation, need to get **JSON** with **Cross-site HTTP requests** and fixed it by using **jQuery** request, instead of **angularjs**

```
$.getJSON('http://www.host.com/test.json', '', function (data) {
    if (meta) {
        console.log("jq success :" + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    console.log("jq success, but empty JSON");
})
    .done(function () {
        console.log("jq second success");
    })
    .fail(function (data) {
        console.log("jq fail " + JSON.stringify(data));
    })
    .always(function () {
        console.log("jq complete");
    });
```

I used Amazon S3 CDN, and **OPTIONS** requests didn't work well with it, so this saved me. The answer from S3 server was:

**This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.**