# OPTIONS request in angular and jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, oauth, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest

I have this weird issue that is happening to me which is confusing me.
I'm developing a frontend website using AngularJS which connects to a server that is using OAuth authentication protocol. to achieve that I was surfing around and came across [angular-auth2](https://github.com/seegno/angular-oauth2) that wraps the OAuth requests.

I made a login controller to handle user login and it depends on [angular-auth2](https://github.com/seegno/angular-oauth2)'s OAuth service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, OAuth) {
  $scope.login = function() {
    var username = $scope.username;
    var password = $scope.password;

    return OAuth.getAccessToken({
      username: username,
      password: password
    }).then(function() {
      console.log(arguments);
    }, function() {
      console.log('ERORRRRRRRRRR!!!!!');
      console.log(arguments);
    });
  };
});
```

and I am calling the login method from my view like this:

```
<form>
  username: <input type="text" ng-model="username"><br />
  password: <input type="password" ng-model="password"><br />
  <button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
</form>
```

When I click the login button with correct credentials for the first time the [angular-auth2](https://github.com/seegno/angular-oauth2) creates a `POST` request to the server and stores the response in a cookie, but whenever I try to make any other request afterwards the `POST` request gets preceded with an `OPTIONS` request which fails with error code 400 and error message of `Bad Request` and if I delete the cookie I don't get an `OPTIONS` request and everything works fine.

The confusing part is I tried to make these requests with jQuery and I was able to send `POST` requests without the `OPTIONS` request at all.

here is my jQuery code:

```
function login(username, password, client_id, apiUrl, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax(apiUrl, {
        data: {
            'grant_type': 'password',
            'client_id': client_id,
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        },
        success: function (data) {
            successCallback(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            errorCallback(data);
        },
        method: 'POST',
    });
};
```

Now I am stuck with this problem of mine, and also got confused of when the `OPTIONS` request is sent and when it is not.

Comment: You may want to look into CORS. OPTIONS requests precede most CORS requests.

Answer (score 0):

The preflight OPTIONS request is not an angular-thing but rather a part of the implementation of XMLHttpRequest.

> Complex cross-origin HTTP requests require a pre-flight OPTIONS
>   request so the browser can find out if the other server will grant
>   permission for the Ajax request
>
> Short of making sure the Ajax request you are making is simple, there is no way to prevent the OPTIONS request.
>
> > A simple request:
> >
> > Only uses GET, HEAD or POST. If POST is used to send data to the server, the Content-Type of the data sent to the server with the HTTP POST request is one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.
> >     Does not set custom headers with the HTTP Request (such as X-Modified, etc.)

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24656672/128129

For instance if you do a POST-request with JSON-encoded body it will be considered a complex request - and thus require a pre-flight options request.